# Get click array item

Tags: javascript

trying to call an array from model.data in catListView.render(), it's showing perfectly but how to make the array item clickable, (i.e cat0 is clicked or cat2 is click).

```
$(function () {
var model = {
    data: ["cat0", "cat1", "cat2", "cat3"],
}

var oct = {
    init: function () {
        catList.init();
    },
    getCat: function () {
        return model.data;
    },
};

var catListView = {
    init: function () {
        this.$catList = $("#cat-list");
        catList.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        var catList = this.$catList.html('');

        var cats = oct.getCat();

        for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
            var cat = cats[i];

            var li = "<li>" + cat + "</li>";
            addEventListener(li, "click", function(){                    
                console.log(this.li.text());
            });
            catList.append(li);
        }
    }
};

oct.init();
}());
```

Comment: try li.addEventListener('click', function(){                    
                console.log(this.li.text());
});

Comment: already tried this, getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: li.addEventListener is not a function"

Comment: var li = "<li onClick='somefunction(this)'>" + cat + "</li>";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind an eventListener to the EventTarget using EventTarget.addEventListener() when using pure DOM (see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener for reference).

So in your code it would be:

```
var li = document.createElement('li'); // create an element instead if string

li.innerText = cat;

li.addEventListener("click", function(){                    
    console.log(li.innerText);
});
```

Note that you also need to create a DOM element to bind events to.

Comment: logically it should be done as per your solution, and already tried this but getting this error  getting this error **"Uncaught TypeError: li.addEventListener is not a function"**

Comment: Edit; was too fast. You can't bind to strings, but should bind to DOM elements. Hence just create an element. You can insert the li into the DOM using the jQuery append or the pure DOM methods then.

Comment: yes, I find the solution in pure JS, but I am trying to do this in JQuery. and damm, its give me headache, might I missing very small thing, 
array value is fetch and display it in li and its working fine, but how to exactly bind each item with its own making me pain

Comment: To create the element using jquery just do a var li = $("<li>" + cat + "</li>"); li.click(function () { /* do whatever here */ }); catList.append(li); - this should create the element as well, .click binds a click listener to it.

Comment: when bind through **on** or **click** its give me TypeError "Uncaught TypeError: li.on is not a function"

Comment: Did you also wrap your code in the $('<li>anything</li>') block? This is important to create the jQuery object out of it.

Comment: here is the repository  https://github.com/udacity/ud989-cat-clicker-premium-vanilla, again its in JS but I am trying to do it in JQuery. check the line 123-142 in js>app.js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144907/discussion-between-severin-and-faisal).

Comment: thanks alot for your solution @severin :)
solution : 
            $li.on("click",(function(copycat){
                return function(){
                    console.log(copycat);
                }
            })(cat));

Answer (score 0):

The codes you typed cannot run... I try to guess what you want-

```
$li.bind("click", function() {
  console.log("way 2", $(this).index());
});
```

https://codepen.io/linjiyeah/pen/QvzVQN

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: li.bind is not a function :(

Comment: There are some differences between DOM and Jquery Object... You can create a Jquery Object like the below code.
    var li = $("<li>" + cat + "</li>");